# SoftwareSerial receives beginning of data mangled

Tags: softwareserial, data-type

I'm using SoftwareSerial to communicate with a Sigfox module. Documentation for the [`read`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialRead) function assigns its value to a `char`. However using it I get mangled characters and also have read in other question that I should assign it to `int` as it can return `-1` for no data and `[0;255]` for received character.

This is my basic troubleshooting example:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Sigfox(11,10);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // HW serial
  Sigfox.begin(9600); // SW serial --> sigfox
}

void loop() {
  if(Sigfox.available()) {
    int c = Sigfox.read();
    Serial.write(c);
  }
  if(Serial.available()) Sigfox.write(Serial.read());
}
```

When `c` is char, I get `-5` instead of `OK`. Also other output is mangled. When `c` is int, it receives the data OK.

My question is - why they use `char` in the example in documentation? Why is `char` signed in Arduino?

I want to read the entire line of text from serial port and store it into array. How to define that array? I have found an example on web that uses `char buffer[32]`, but then again I get mangled data when I assign to it. If I use array of `byte`/`int`/`unsigned char`, I can't print it as `Serial.write(SF_buffer);` won't compile because of `no matching function for call to 'write(unsigned char [32])'`.

So what variable types should I use to receive and store the text from SoftwareSerial correctly?

Here is my function for reading the whole line:

```
unsigned char SF_buffer [32]; // max length of line to read from serial
bool SigfoxReadine() { // return true when whole line was received and is in buffer
  static int SF_cnt=0;
  while (Sigfox.available()) {
    int c = Sigfox.read();
    SF_buffer[SF_cnt++] = c;
    if ((c == '\n') || (SF_cnt == sizeof(SF_buffer)-1)) {
       SF_buffer[SF_cnt] = '\0';
       SF_cnt = 0;
       return(true);
    }
  }
  return(false);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Trying `readBytesUntil` - the same result, but I have found that issue is only when I send data to module using `println` as in this example:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Sigfox(11,10);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // HW serial
  Sigfox.begin(9600); // SW serial --> sigfox
  Sigfox.println("AT$I=11");
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) Sigfox.write(Serial.read());
  SF_read();
}

void SF_read() {
  if (Sigfox.available()) {
    char buff[32];
    int l = Sigfox.readBytesUntil('\n', buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (l > 0 && buff[l - 1] == '\r') {
      l--; // to remove \r if it is there
    }
    buff[l] = 0; // terminate the string
    Serial.println(buff);
  }
}
```

The response to first command (in setup) is mangled. The response to the same AT command manually written into serial monitor (and sent to module via Sigfox.write in loop) is OK.

> ӂ*⸮FBB1E27EE7
>
> 3430E2FBB1E27EE7

Also maybe I'm little lost in when to use print and when write... Example says to use `write()` to send back the char that was `read()`. Juraj's response uses `println()` to print the null-terminated buffer. What is the difference when I write/println this buffer?

Comment: refer to this when dealing with char data type ... http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: yes, using `int` data type is advisable ... if you use `byte` data type, then there is a conflict between data and an error flag ... a `-1` is equivalent to hex `0xff`, which is decimal `255` .... for `int` type, the decimal 255 is represented as `0x00ff` and `-1` is represented as 0xffff ... no conflict between those two .... please note that only a single byte is transmitted over serial ... the two byte `int` is created by the serial library so that your sketch has a way of receiving an error status from the library

Comment: `Serial.write(SF_buffer, length);` or for null terminated char array `Serial.print(SF_buffer);`

Comment: @Juraj if `SF_buffer` is char type, I get mangled output (`SF_buffer[SF_cnt++]=c;`). How to assign the `int c` into the `char` array correctly?

Comment: use byte. does the devices send characters with ascii codes above 127?

Comment: @Juraj usually not. But with `char` I got mangled for example original "OK" into "-5". I think I tried `byte` yesterday, but will try again when I get home.

Comment: did you wire ground? `Serial.write(Sigfox.read());` must work

Comment: @Juraj yes I did :) That one works. It breaks when I save the value from read to variable and try to write that variable back. If I save it to `char`, "OK" prints as "-5". If I save it as `byte` or `int`, it prints OK, but then I have issue how to save whole line into array of chars.

Comment: what Arduino do you use?

Comment: @Juraj Arduino Pro Mini, Serial is connected to FTDI and USB. SoftwareSerial is Sigfox Wisol module. Arduino 1.8.9.

Answer (score 2):

I like the readBytes or readBytesUntil function. It doesn't end on a small gap between received bytes and fills the buffer. This functions are blocking with timeout, but if read some other device the input is usually fast and terminated reliably.

example for readBytesUntil:

```
if (Serial.available()) {
  char buff[32];
  int l = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buff, sizeof(buff));
  if (l > 0 && buff[l - 1] == '\r') {
    l--; // to remove \r if it is there
  }
  buff[l] = 0; // terminate the string
  Serial.println(buff);
}
```

Comment: does readBytes exist also for SoftwareSerial? Documentation mentions it only for Serial

Comment: it is in the Stream base class

Comment: @Marki555, did it help?

Comment: testing... seems more strange now :) the issue from yesterday now seems to exist only when sending data to via Sigfox.println and not when using Sigfox.write...

Comment: edited the question with new findings

Comment: Found the issue! Thanks for troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 1):

Last test showed it mangles data only when using `println()` and doesn't depend on the `char` type. Then I remembered something about CRLF in the Sigfox datasheet:

> Is recommended to use full duplex UART. In case of using half duplex, AT
>   commands has to be ended only with one of ‘\r’ or ‘\n’ not both. Because if you send
>   “AT\r\n” the Sigfox devkit starts sending “OK” instantly after it receive ‘\r’, but
>   microcontroller is still sending byte ‘\n’.

SoftwareSerial is in fact [half-duplex only](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/arduino-software-serial-full-duplex) (although I didn't find it in the reference documentation) and `println()` sends both '\r' and '\n', so while sending the later, Sigfox module is already trying to send back the answer, which gets mangled by SoftwareSerial.

Feel free to add your answer to explain why `char` is signed in Arduino and when to use `print()` and when `write()` with serial port.